# Is there a way to filter individuals

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Suppose, hypothetically, there is a person on this site who asks many questions every day. I would like a way to view new questions, but filter out particular posters so it's a bit more readable. Is this possible?

Comment: You can search for `user:{user_id}` to find posts by a specific user. I would've thought adding a `-` before it would invert that (like how every search tool works), but apparently that doesn't work.

Comment: I would support some sort of controlled trial of such a feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature has [been discussed for as long as over 14 years](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3353/add-the-ability-to-ignore-users).

The long and short story of it is that since SE is a content-driven and not a social site, this will probably not be possible. Ever.

There are scripts out there to make it happen anyway, though.

Comment: I would argue that for some, content is driven by a narcissistic desire to accumulate reputation points

Comment: @IdiosyncraticSoul I agree, that's why I started to close questions right away.